# Selenium for MacOS Setup

Tags: selenium, java, eclipse

I wanted to know if there is a good source for setting up Selenium in Eclipse on MacOS. I have MacOS 10.9.4.

Comment: What exactly are your questions? Does following the installation instructions for Unix not work?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I'm not sure how to use Selenium on my Mac, is there a guide out there to follow? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Java jar from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/. Unzip the file and move the (non-source) jar to where you keep your libraries for your Eclipse project.

In Eclipse, you will need to add the jar to the list of libraries for your project build.

You should now be able to create a test class and run some Selenium tests. There is a good starter test class in the Selenium documentation at http:seleniumhq.org.

**Assumptions**

All of the above assumes:

1. You are using Java in Eclipse and you know how to set up Eclipse projects.
2. You can unzip and move files to where you need them and know how to a jar to your list of libraries.
3. You have a unit/function testing framework such as JUnit or TestNG.
4. You know how to write Java programs.